# Sharing variable across QStackedWidget pages

Tags: qt, combobox, qt4

I have StackedWidget with 3 pages, every page contain 3 lineEdit, now at every page I pass, I want to save the content of this 3 lineEdit into a variable to be able later handle it.
I have this piece of code:

```
connect(ui->stackedWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(getInputs(int)));
```

And the slot:

```
void ConfSetup::getInputs(int index)
{
    QString para;

    switch(index)
     {
        case 1:
            ui->backButton0->setEnabled(false);
        break;

        case 2:
            inputs << ui->serverEdit->text();
            inputs << ui->portEdit->text();
        break;

        case 3:
            inputs << ui->userDbEdit->text();
            inputs << ui->passwordDbEdit->text();
        break;

        case 6:
            foreach(para, inputs)
               ui->comboBox->addItem(para);
            //ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(para.length()));
        break;

        default:
            ui->backButton0->setEnabled(true);
        break;
     }
}
```

The `comboBox` widget should now contains 4 values, but rather then it contains a blank text, also `para.length()` return 0 in `lineEdit` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend tell me that I am filling the `inputs` variable at time I change the index page, witch mean of course the `lineEdit` widgets are empty at that time. The solution is very simple, first, I avoid `getInputs(int )` slot, and in replacement I make this:

```
ui->comboBox->addItem(ui->serverEdit->text());
ui->comboBox->addItem(ui->portEdit->text());
ui->comboBox->addItem(ui->userDbEdit->text());
// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use member variables in your main window? Just declare them in your header file and initialize in your cpp.

```
// your header file
QString m_server_str;
QString m_port_str;
QString m_userdb_str;
QString m_passworddb_str;
```

And when switching a page of your QStackedWidget you read the content of the edits and save them to your member variable. Just use them same signal as you already do: `QStackedWidget::currentChanged ( int index )`

Comment: Would you explain the wrong of `QStringList inputs`, because to me looks as some setting many members. I just tried your suggestion, and I get the some result (blank text).

Comment: remember that *index* is the number of the new page that you have changed to. maybe you took the wrong page and need to store the index of the current page first.